# Photography website platform examples

Tags: wordpress, photo-gallery

I am looking forward to create a website with my own photography portfolio.
Which are the best solutions on market so I won't have to pay for hosting, i don't mind even for domain that much?
I also thought for wordpress platform, but I don't know which are the limits.
I will also want to put adsense advertises so I will get somehow an income.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want static pages then you can use galerrific

http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-5.html

or if you want php-mysql kind of image gallery you could chose one from

http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=7&category=Image%20Galleries

they have demo there.